# In App purchase vs new App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an App currently in the App store that I've been adding functionality to.  I've never worked with In-App purchases, but from what I have been reading, it looks like the "improvements" offered are code adjustments to add, or unlock features.

For my "improved" version, I actually added an entirely new (additional) VC plus a Master VC to switch between the two (using the storyboard), so it's not just a matter of unlocking code to provide the additional features.  Can I still use the In-App purchase to provide access to this version, or would I have to submit it as an entirely new product?

Comment: Why would you think you need to submit an entirely new product?

Comment: Hi rmaddy, mostly because the changes I would make would entail a completely different program architecture, whereas I was working within one VC in the initial app, I would be using two VCs and a Master controller.  Once I implement the MC, I (I am a new programmer, so there might be a way I don't know, but...) don't think I can just use code to switch from one format to another.  I'm not familiar with how in-app purchases are accomplished, but I assumed it had to be build into the app.  If it can be a replaced version, like when you update, then it would be fine, but if not, would be new app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add some kind of "premium" feature that only people who pay X amount will have access to, but are still maintaining a "basic" version of the app for everyone else, then yes, you can create an In App Purchase to do this.  Or, if you wanted to, you could create a separate "premium" version of your app.  It's really up to you.  I wouldn't necessarily say one way is preferred over the other, because I've seen it done both ways.

Comment: Thanks!!  Not having worked with in-app purchases before, I not sure if i made changes that I could not just build into the original as turn-on/off feature (due to the use of a second VC and Master Controller in the updated version), it could be done as an in-app (my preferred way to go).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you wanted to charge for the new features, they are not present in the currently released version of your app, so no matter how you decide to market this, you will have to submit a new version of your app. It can contain an in-app purchase or not, but it will be a new version. It certainly does not have to be a different app; adding functionality, possibly including an in-app purchase, is what a new version is for.

Comment: Right....  I'd not want to do it just as a new version for update because not all users may want the additional features... plus I'd want to put an additional value to the features so the pricing would change.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you don't need to add a totally new app in any case unless and until you want one more app to be on app store

Detailed answer: If you are just making changes in the underlying architecture of your app it doesn't make any sense to give it to user as in app purchase( and i guess apple will also reject your in-app products). You should only add in-app purchase if you are adding a new feature or giving the user some bonus stuff.

And as per me you should add new version of the app only if you feel that this is a new app.( for example Badlands and Badlands 2 are similar apps but internally they are different from each other so they uploaded them as badlands 2)